# How can I have puppet use a local (on the master) password hash for users?

Tags: linux, puppet, configuration-management

We define users as such:

```
user { 'belmin':
    ensure          => present,
    uid             => 308,
    comment         => 'Belmin Fernandez',
    managehome      => true,
    password        => '$6$NrtZpXEauUqjdRh0$vE9oJwbNTSWVCGrlDe4KHXFB0KXY7hszSas3v0DZvhUej4SIb/WLfaCy.lmSU7Hh8AAvAbPuDRai2p1X9mDcM0',
}
```

I want to define a type that will look in the `/etc/shadow` local to the puppet master and, if the user is there, use that password hash instead. Something like:

```
define our_user ($user = $title, $uid, $fullname, $default_hash) {

    $shadow_hash = get_hash_from_local_shadown_somehow

    if $shadow_hash == '' {
        $shadow_hash = $default_hash
    }

    user { $user:
        ensure          => present,
        uid             => $uid,
        comment         => $fullname,
        managehome      => true,
        password        => $shadow_hash,
    }
}
```

What would `get_hash_from_local_shadown_somehow` be in this case? I see the [file function](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#file) in `puppet` but unsure how to utilize that to address this since I'll need some more text processing.

*Note: I know that centralized authentication would be the wisest avenue but that isn't an immediate option at the moment.*

Comment: i don't think there is a good way to handle this without exposing the user's password in the manifest. Is there a reason you can't use ssh keys instead?

Comment: That would require substantial organizational policy changes. I would rather band-aid this and then focus on deploying centralized authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to do this via [Puppet's forum](http://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/13668/how-can-i-have-puppet-use-a-local-on-the-master-password-hash-for-users/) using the [generate](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#generate) function:

> You can use the generate() function to that.
>
> You'd basically create a script that does whatever processing you
>   need, then $shadow_hash = generate('/path/to/script').

I wrote a simple bash script to retrieve the hash:

```
#!/bin/bash

SHADOW_FILE='/etc/shadow'

awk -F: "\$1 == \"$@\"" ${SHADOW_FILE} | awk -F: '{print $2}' || echo ''
```

And the `generate` function looks like so:

```
$shadow_hash = generate('/bin/bash','/usr/local/sbin/extract_shadow_hash', $user)
```

Hope this helps someone else. Seems like a function that could be useful in a bunch of use cases.